# Monacaのプッシュ通知でバイブレーションを実行したい

Tags: monaca

Monacaでプッシュ通知を送信すると、通知には出るのですが、バイブレーションでの通知がされません。

下記のコードをindex.htmlの内で書いていますが、
そもそもmonaca.cloud.Push.setHandlerの中にイベントが実行されません。
どこかおかしいところがあればご指摘ください。

```
// プッシュ通知振動確認
ons.ready(function(){
  monaca.cloud.Push.setHandler(function(data) {
    navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
    });
});
```

なお、iPhone側での通知の設定は確認済みです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

すみません。自己解決しました。
Monacaデバッガーだと最初から設定されているプラグインが有効になっていませんでした。

Cordovaのプラグインでnavigator.notificationの設定を有効化してビルドすることで解決しました。